# PCI Express Root Complex Drivers on Windows Installation

Tags: windows, drivers, ssd

I'm trying to install Windows from a USB drive to a new SSD, but at the fresh install screen I end up with an error stating that I have to provide PCI Express Root Complex drivers. I can't find much reliable documentation about this problem online.

Some details about the build. Everything was bought second hand apart from the SSD, which was bought new:

Motherboard: X299 UD4 Pro
SSD: Samsung 860 EVO

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: On most computers this is the free fall sensor. The mystery is W10 should install without the driver.

Comment: Since that is a desktop board it should not have this sensor.

Comment: I would contact Gigabyte support about the issue.

Comment: We reinstalled the motherboard BIOS and still get the same issue. Is it confirmed that this must be a related to the free-fall sensor? I found people discussing this in relation to Dell laptops. Can you provide a link to something corroborating this in more general terms? I couldn't find anything on Microsoft's own website relating to this. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Desktop boards do not have that sensor, I just googled your title, all articles are related to laptops.